# Angular templating not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I`m just starting out with AngularJS and I`m having trouble with this piece of code.

This is the code from my js file called cribsController.js:

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
.controller('cribsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello = 'Hello world!';
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>ng-cribs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
    <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.5/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.5/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
```

When I view the html file, instead of displaying Hellow world!, I get {{hello}}.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Also could you show your `app.js`?

Comment: I deleted my answer about the non existing module. We do need to see what's inside `app.js`

Comment: Check console for possible errors.

Comment: And don't include both `ui-bootstrap.min.js` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` - leave only `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` in the document (unless you defined your own html templates, then use the other file)

Comment: Here is the code form my app.js:

angular.modules('ngCribs', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: The error I'm getting seeing in the console is, TypeError: angular.modules is not a function

Comment: Got it, I removed the 's' from angular.models and it works now. Thanks for the console tip everyone. I'll pay more attention to that going forward.

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is working in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QV8BrWsxW0KgocAwDkZj?p=preview).

All I did was wrap the code in a function call.

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';

 angular.module('ngCribs', [])
.controller('cribsController', function($scope){
$scope.hello = 'Hello';
 });
})(window.angular);
```